# WPF - Simpler method for Geometry animation without TranslateTransform

Tags: c#, wpf

The following code works and animates the associated `GlyphRun` object by an offset of (200, 200), and the text moves along the path indicated by the red arrow, over a duration of 1.250 seconds:

```
Geometry grg = _glyphRun.BuildGeometry();                         
drawingContext.DrawGeometry(Brushes.Black, null, grg);            
grg.Transform = new TranslateTransform(0, 0);                     
Duration duration = new Duration(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 1, 250));    
DoubleAnimation anim = new DoubleAnimation(200, duration);          
anim.EasingFunction = new QuarticEase();                            
grg.Transform.BeginAnimation(TranslateTransform.XProperty, anim);   
grg.Transform.BeginAnimation(TranslateTransform.YProperty, anim);
```

[image]

However, I don't understand the need for the `TranslateTransform` that is involved, because of its zero-offset point.

Could the above animation be achieved in a simpler manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the properties of the `TranslateTransform` which are being animated. The object is initialized to `(0, 0)`, but as the animation progresses, the `X` and `Y` properties of that object are modified. It is, in fact, this modification that causes the glyph to be iteratively moved per the animation.

As for whether it could be achieved in a simpler manner, well…that's a bit of "eye of the beholder" sort of thing. Personally, I'd consider it "simpler" to declare the animation in XAML instead of writing code-behind to do it. So in that sense, sure…it absolutely could be done more simply.

Beyond that, if all that's being drawn is simple text, it seems to me that placing a `TextBlock` in a `Canvas` and animating that `TextBlock` object's `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` properties would also be considered simpler. Frankly, any number of other options *might* be considered simpler. Or not, depending on what your idea of "simpler" is.